# After upgrade of retail iWork 09 DVD it appeard on my Apple Store account

Tags: mac-appstore, iwork

I found my iWork 09 retail DVD, which I bought 4.5 years ago. After I installed it, Apple Store showed me that I've got an **upgrade** to version 13. Next, it appeared on my Apple Store account in purchases, after upgrade. Is it normal behaviour or it is a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a normal behaviour so you can directly download the new Pages, Keynote & Numbers on your new Macs (or new OSX installations).